# How to fix boolean check and check if var is not undefined

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm writing a code that needs to check if `$scope.bankregel`, `$scope.showInvoices` is true or false.

In my function on the if and else if I'm already checking on a conditional. How can I add an extra conditional in the if and else if?

This is what I have tried

```
    $scope.filterItems = function(){
    if($scope.bankregel || $scope.banklines != undefined){
        var begin = (($scope.curPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage),
            end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;

        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.banklines.slice(begin, end);
    }
    else if ($scope.showInvoices || $scope.invoices != undefined){
        var begin = (($scope.curPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage),
            end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;

        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.invoices.slice(begin, end);
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me out and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Question is not clear ? What are your conditions ? What your existing code states here is, IF `$scope.bankregel` is TRUE OR `$scope.banklines` IS NOT UNDEFINED

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, $scope.bankregel and $scope.showInvoices need to be checked if its true or false. $scope.banklines != undefined and $scope.invoices != undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$scope.filterItems = function(){
    if(typeof $scope.banklines !== "undefined" && $scope.bankregel){
        var begin = (($scope.curPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage),
            end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;

        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.banklines.slice(begin, end);
    }
    else if ( typeof $scope.invoices !== "undefined" && $scope.showInvoices){
        var begin = (($scope.curPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage),
            end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;

        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.invoices.slice(begin, end);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$scope.filterItems = function(){
    if($scope.bankregel && $scope.banklines != undefined){
        var begin = (($scope.curPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage),
            end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;

        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.banklines.slice(begin, end);
    }
    else if ($scope.showInvoices && $scope.invoices != undefined){
        var begin = (($scope.curPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage),
            end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;

        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.invoices.slice(begin, end);
    }
}
```